# Trigger child onchange handler from click on parent element with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, jsx, mouseevent

I want to expand the clickable area of a Select component I have that I don't have access to change it (comes from a lib).

This Select component is wrapped by a div... I thought about adding a click handler to this div so that when a user clicks on it, it triggers the click on the Select. It would do it, if the select also had an `onClick` handler, but instead, of course, it has an `onChange`, which is not triggered.

I wanted help to find a proper way to trigger it.

This is a simplified version of my JSX code:

```
<div data-testid="language-select">
  <MyCustomSelect
    id="language-selector"
    options={languageList.map(({ locale, title }) => ({
      value: locale,
      children: title,
    }))}
    value={currentLocale}
    onChange={({ target: { value } }): void => {
      global.location.replace(resolveUrl(value));
    }}
  />
</div>;
```

**What I did:**

Added `onClick` to div:

```
onClick={() => {
  const languageSelector = document.getElementById('language-selector');
  languageSelector?.click();
}}
```

But then as I said it doesn't work as it doesn't trigger the change.

Is there a proper way to achieve this behavior?

EDIT:
I created this sandbox to help understanding my issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wildflower-0ido5j?file=/src/App.js:561-569

So I want to find a way to click on the red part (the div), and fire the select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` to access child component methods, but it should let you do click event

```
<div data-testid="language-select">
  <MyCustomSelect
    id="language-selector"
    options={languageList.map(({ locale, title }) => ({
      value: locale,
      children: title,
    }))}
    value={currentLocale}
    onChange={({ target: { value } }): void => {
      global.location.replace(resolveUrl(value));
    }}
   ref={ref} // Pass ref
  />
</div>
```

Div click

```
ref.current.onClick
```

It will be good if you can share a library which your are using or a working demo for the issue

Comment: it didn't work.. I tried to create a dummy example and edited the question to include it.
So by clicking on the red area, we should trigger the select.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wildflower-0ido5j

Answer (score 0):

you could try referencing the select

like:

```
  import React, { useRef } from 'react';
  .
  .
  .
  const SelectRef = useRef(null)
  render (
    <div onClick={()=> SelectRef.current.click()}>
      <MyCustomSelect
        id="language-selector"
        ref={SelectRef}
        options={languageList.map(({ locale, title }) => ({
          value: locale,
          children: title,
        }))}
        value={currentLocale}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }): void => {
          global.location.replace(resolveUrl(value));
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

It may not work, can you let me know.

Edit:

```
  import React, { useRef } from 'react';
  .
  .
  .
  const SelectRef = useRef(null)
  render (
    <div onClick={()=> SelectRef.current.focus()}>
      <MyCustomSelect
        id="language-selector"
        ref={SelectRef}
        options={languageList.map(({ locale, title }) => ({
          value: locale,
          children: title,
        }))}
        value={currentLocale}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }): void => {
          global.location.replace(resolveUrl(value));
        }}
        openMenuOnFocus
      />
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: it didn't work.. and I debugged it.. SelectRef is being passed and has current property... but doesn't do the job :/

Comment: can you try focus instead of click and add `openMenuOnFocus` to your select

Comment: I think this openMenuOnFocus belongs to react-select library, which is not my case :/ I used it in the sandbox just to make it simpler to build the select :/